# shuffle multidimensional List, ArrayList, LinkedList

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections

As we know shuffling an `ArrayList` can be done with the method `Collections.shuffle`.

But how does that work with a multidimensional sequential collection?

if I have a pattern as follows:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

I want to achieve something like this:

```
1,5,7
2,3,8
9,4,6
```

Collection.shuffle() only swaps either the rows or columns, but I want to swap all elements completely independend.

I WANT NOT:

```
1,3,2
5,6,4
7,9,8
```

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: a arraylist where all elements become randomly shuffeled

Comment: I extended my answer with a solution for your adapted question.

Comment: question is still the same

Answer (score 1):

If you just call `Collection.shuffle` on the multidimensional list, it will shuffle the order of the sublists within that list.

If you instead want to shuffle all the sublists, you have to call `Collection.shuffle` for each sublist.

```
final List<List<String>> list = Arrays.asList(
        Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"),
        Arrays.asList("X", "Y", "Z"),
        Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3")

);

// 1. Will shuffle the order of the sub-lists
Collections.shuffle(list);

// 2.a. Will shuffle all the sub-lists
list.forEach(sublist -> Collections.shuffle(sublist));

// 2.b. Or the same, with method reference instead of lambda
list.forEach(Collections::shuffle);
```

## Edit after edited question

If the requirement is really to shuffle all elements of all sublists and even mix elements between sublist, above code will not be sufficient.

The below code will do as you request, but it will assume that *all sublists have the same size* (in this case `3`):

```
// 1. Add all values in single dimension list    
List<String> allValues = list.stream()
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(toList());

// 2. Shuffle all those values
Collections.shuffle(allValues);

// 3. Re-create the multidimensional List
List<List<String>> shuffledValues = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < allValues.size(); i = i + 3) {
    shuffledValues.add(allValues.subList(i, i+3));
}
```

Comment: i want to do both shuffle sublists and shuffle elements in each sublist so that all elements get a completepy new order.

Comment: Ok, then my posted piece of code above will do exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a deep shuffle, I would recommend an approach that checks whether each item in the list is another list, and shuffle that list, recursively.  Something like this:

```
public static void deepShuffle(List<?> mutliDimensionList) {
    for (Object item : mutliDimensionList) {
        if (item instanceof List) {
            deepShuffle((List<?>)item);
        }
    }
    Collections.shuffle(mutliDimensionList);
}
```

You can add multithreading to potentially increase performance with a ForkJoinPool or something similar.  That's entirely dependent on your use case though.

**Edit** This answer no longer applies to the edited question.  However it should work when individual sublists need to be shuffled independently.